# Storing a copy of current object

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a class :

```
`class Myclass
{
   public:
     MyClass ( void );
     AddNumber ( const int num );
     CopyCurrentObject ( void );

   private:
     int * array
     int size;
     int maxSize;
     MyClass * objetcts[10];
}
```

> How can I create a copy of my current object and save it to `MyClass * objects[10]`?

With the copy I mean that I want to  create a temporary object with current values of my current object ( elements in array, size, maxSize ) and store it to the `MyClass * objects[10]`. It's basically something like back-up.

I create the temporary object and store the object to array like this :

`MyClass * temp = new MyClass ( * this ); 
 MyClass objects[cnt++] = temp;`

The problem is with  `int * array` because this way it's pointing to my object array so whenever i add a value in my object, stored objects in `MyClass * objects[10]` have it too.

Comment: Take more care. Sort out your typos. I see three in your code straight off.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the copy constructor and the assignment operator.

`Myclass(const Myclass& orig);
  Myclass& operator=(const Myclass& orig);`